# How do I display the content type's description in a view's header?

Tags: 8, views

I have a view that lists nodes of a single content type, where the content type is given as contextual filter.

I'd like to add the name of the content type and a description to the header, for example as the following.

> ### Content Type: Cooking
>
> The Cooking content type is for cooking-related content

I can show the content type name by by adding a hidden field to the view and then using `<h1>{{ type }}</h1>` in the header, but I don't see such an option for the description.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

First, add then config the contextual filter like this:
[image: config the contextual filter to update the display's title]

Then you update the header like this:

### [image: Update header using new display's title]
You can update the header status at this step also.

And then here is the result:

[image: Result after updating the header]

**One more thing need you to handle:**

The exception when the filter value is not in the url.
Can it be your part?